# Exe4J Exe mode internal error 16

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, exe4j

What does

> Internal Error. Error code(16)

message box say when application is bundled with Exe4J? I created a jar in exe mode and it pointed out this when started the application.

Answer (score 0):

The internal error occurs when the jvm versions that used as minimum and maximum are not available in the System that the .exe is running.

Hope it helps.